# SNMP net-snmp getting different than expected OID translation

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have RFC1628_UPS_MIB (UPS-MIB) and SNMPv2-SMI (SNMPv2-SMI) installed on my system.

I am using net-snmp tool snmptrapd to receive traps.

Traps from my Liebert NPower UPS are being translated through SNMPv2-SMI rather than UPS-MIB as I expect.

I get `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.33.1.6.3.16` when I am expecting `UPS-MIB::upsAlarmFanFailure`

Some troubleshooting information:

```
    # snmptranslate -On UPS-MIB::upsAlarmFanFailure
    .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.6.3.16
    # snmptranslate .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.6.3.16
    SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.33.1.6.3.16
```

It seems that both MIBS define the same OID and I lost the coin toss. I am very new to SNMP so I don't expect that I have discovered a flaw in the implementation. Can anybody explain what is happening here or point me to a resource that might?

Comment: How did you install UPS-MIB on this machine? Did you get all its dependencies as well?

Comment: @LexLi It looks like I never told net-snmp about this mib.  My system did not have a snmp.conf by default so net-snmp was only using the default set of mibs.  In testing I was using -mAll on the command line. snmptrapd wasn't set up to use -m all. I will add an answer for this question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

net-snmp will only use the default set of mibs by default.  Adding new mibs to the mibs directory is not enough to get snmptrapd to use the new mib.

The simplest way to get all of the net-snmp tools to see any new mibs added to the mib directory is to add the line `mibs ALL` to `snmp.conf`.

My system did not have a default snmp.conf so I created the file `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` with the single line `mibs ALL`

My net-snmp tools including snmptrapd are now able to report the proper oid translations.

Thanks to @LexLi for prompting me to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you nice question and response as well

When someone add enterprise MIB to the standard system MIB. (1.3.6.4.1.#####.1*)

There are most important two steps:

1. etc/snmp/snmp.conf

mibs: (before) ---> you need to change mibs ALL

2. Add your mibs to here

/usr/share/snmp/mibs/

After that you must be restart on the system.

and test the command

snmpwalk -v2c -c public address  (192.168.1.1)

snmpget -v2c -c public address (192.168.1.1) .1.3.6.1.4.1.#####.1

Keep on going. Well

Comment: Does this add anything over the accepted answer from four years ago?

Comment: Important is people to know how problem coming, not only comments person as well.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit, do you have experice concerning implementation of SNMP. My steps are all correct, but  (No such object available on this agent at this OID). I any afford more respected

Comment: Yes, I have implemented a full SNMP agent just recently. But my comment isn't about that. It's about curation and it seems this answer adds nothing new I'm afraid!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, well enterprise MIB added, testing step has issues as (No such object available on this agent at this OID). Please. If any idea.more respected